# delete a functionif it exists in userform by vba coding

Tags: vba

Delete a subroutine in userform using vba coding.I have tried this code

```
Sub DeleteProcedureCode( _
    ByVal DeleteFromModuleName As String, ByVal ProcedureName As String)
' deletes ProcedureName from DeleteFromModuleName in wb
Dim VBCM As CodeModule, ProcStartLine As Long, ProcLineCount As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    Set VBCM = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(DeleteFromModuleName).CodeModule
    If Not VBCM Is Nothing Then
        ' determine if the procedure exist in the codemodule
        ProcStartLine = 0
        ProcStartLine = VBCM.ProcStartLine(ProcedureName, vbext_pk_Proc)
        If ProcStartLine > 0 Then ' prosedyren finnes, slett den
            ProcLineCount = VBCM.ProcCountLines(ProcedureName, vbext_pk_Proc)
            VBCM.DeleteLines ProcStartLine, ProcLineCount
        End If
        Set VBCM = Nothing
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

but this throws an error saying user defined not defined

Comment: Why would you ever need to deleted a sub? Can't you simple ignore it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to delete a procedure, but I can give you a similar behaviour:

```
Public lockedProcedures As Variant

Sub lockProcedure(name As String)
    If Not IsArray(lockedProcedures) Then
        ReDim lockedProcedures(1) As String
    Else
        ReDim Preserve lockedProcedures(UBound(lockedProcedures) + 1)
    End If

    lockedProcedures(UBound(lockedProcedures)) = name
End Sub

Function isLocked(name As String)
    If (UBound(Filter(lockedProcedures, name)) > -1) Then
        MsgBox name & " is locked!"
        isLocked = True
    Else
        isLocked = False
    End If
End Function

Sub test()
    Call lockProcedure("test2")
End Sub

Sub test2()
    if not isLocked("test2") then
        Code...
    end if
End Sub
```